# Drools - KieServices.Factory.get() returns null

Tags: java, drools, kie

I try to integrate a Drools project in a maven application.
The Drools app is running perfectly on his own, but when I try to integrate it in the Maven project, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException.
After some researches it seems to happen because KieServices.Factory.get()  return me something, but all his parameters are null.

Here is my code :

```
 public static final void main(String[] args) {
    myBool test = new myBool(false) ;
    try {
        // load up the knowledge base

        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();

        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

        // go !
       Person toto = new Person("toto",21);
       Person titi = new Person("titi",12);
       Person tata = new Person("tata",15);

        kSession.insert(toto);
```

I already did a lot of resarches, and try a lot of things to fix it (I've already added the dependency of drools-compiler).
Does someone have an idea to fix it ? Thanks !

Comment: "session-rules" session not created. https://www.javainuse.com/drools/drools_decision

Comment: no need to do research. Please go a head with above mentioned link. and Welcome to StackOverFlow.

Comment: Rules are not Fired.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but after looking at your link, I don't understand how to correct the problem. It seems to be a problem with the session that is not created, but I don't find in your link how to fix this

Comment: Follow the video and write the code in step by step.First leave the fear from your end.

Comment: Yes, but he is using xls files and nor drl files in this video.
Even then, I have the exactly same thing than the tutorial : My kmodule.xml file, with the kession declared in it, the META-INF/maven/pom.properties files, etc...

Comment: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/spring-boot-drools-hello-world   check this link

Comment: Still the same problem,  KieServices.Factory.get() is returning something with all parameters "null", so the getKieClasspathContainer() method is not working and it cannot initialisate my rule session

Comment: give ur person mail id .. i will share my project.